# Empty array returned when calling AlphaVantage APIs for NASDAQ tickers

Tags: stock, alpha-vantage

I cannot get *any* NASDAQ data from the Alpha Vantage TIME_SERIES_DAILY, TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED or TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY -- the returned array is always empty regardless of the equity or index symbol I use:

```
{}
```

This is the call I made to get that array:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=NASDAQ:^IXIC&interval=15min
```

Notice I've used the `NASDAQ:` prefix. I've also tried using `NSQ:` instead -- with exactly the same results. I don't get this issue when calling for LSE (`LON:`) or NYSE (`NYSE:`) data.

I've tried a range of valid and invalid equity ticker symbols (e.g. `GOOGL`, `MSFT`) with either the same empty array result returned (if a valid ticker) or an expected error message returned (if an invalid ticker).

Am I doing something wrong here? Is NASDAQ listed using some other random collection of letters?

I've noticed some inconsistency between real-life ticker symbols, and the AV ticker symbols -- often enough that I've created a translation table so I can represent domain-useful information rather than AV-useful information. I'm hoping I'm just using an incorrect or outdated reference to NASDAQ to call the API.

Your help is much appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR;

Just look up the symbol (ie. `AAPL` or `GOOGL`). The `IXIC` is an index, Alpha Vantage currently does not cover indexes.

---

Further notes:

1. Quotes from [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/) are aggregated, so any price you're getting won't be the price from what it's traded on the NASDAQ, but a quote of what the price is across exchanges.
2. If you're looking for a specific symbol, you can check for what it's listed as using the [search endpoint](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#symbolsearch).
3. [Example here](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo)